# Credit card details autofill in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Will Firefox store credit card details and provide autofill?

The Safari browsre suggests a stored credit card when you switch to a credit card number field. Can Firefox do the same?

Comment: Should be this question moved to superuser?

Answer (score 3):

Firefox does not do so by default.

However, there are various add-ons or programs which will perform this function. Filling in other form information is sometimes included with password managers. You should probably [search on AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=password+manager&appver=35.0.1&platform=WINNT); or [this search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=automatic+form+filling&appver=35.0.1&platform=WINNT).

You can also do a Google search for [Password Manager](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&lr=&as_qdr=all&q=password%20manager) or [Digital Wallet](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&lr=&as_qdr=all&q=digital%20wallet).

Or read a blog post/article:

[Lifehacker: Five Best Password Managers](http://lifehacker.com/5529133/five-best-password-managers)
[PC Mag: The Best Password Managers for 2015](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2407168,00.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Firefox is implementing this, see the firefox blog: https://blog.mozilla.org/firefox/online-shopping-autofill-credit-card-info-safely-firefox/

As january 2018, the feature is not yet available to all users, but it can be set in about:config page: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Features/Form_Autofill